# Calculate using elements' contents in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a calculation using the text of related elements (`mcost_el=mcount_el*mprice_el`) and write the result to the text of another element (to "mcost_el").

```
<tr>
 <td class="mcount_el">2</td>
 <td class="mprice_el">544,33</td>
 <td class="mcost_el">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="mcount_el">3,9</td>
 <td class="mprice_el">460,00</td>
 <td class="mcost_el">0</td>
</tr>
```

I write this code:

```
var count=0;
var price=0;
$('.mcost_el').each(function(){
      count=parseInt($('.mcount_el').each.text().replace(",","."));
      price=parseInt($('.mprice_el').each.text().replace(",","."));
      $('.mcost_el').html(parseFloat(count)*parseFloat(price));
    });
```

but it don't work.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what I understand you're asking, please rollback if this edit is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
   var count=parseFloat($('.mcount_el',this).text().replace(",","."));
   var price=parseFloat($('.mprice_el',this).text().replace(",","."));
   $('.mcost_el', this).html(count*price);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BzVyc/

The difference is that, instead of doing a `parseInt` on the string then a `parseFloat` on the resulting int, you just do a `parseFloat` on the string.

Comment: Is it necessary to replace the commas with decimals? I thought JavaScript handled this sort of localization automatically. (Of course, I've never had to deal with it myself.)

Comment: In your example don't mcost_el identity in each result =(

Comment: @mblase75 - I tried and without the replace the result changes. Looks like javascript wont treat `,` as a decimal place (at least on my machine)

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this -

```
var count=0;
var price=0;
$('tr').each(function(){
      count=parseFloat($(this).find('td.mcount_el').text().replace(",","."));
  price=parseFloat($(this).find('td.mprice_el').text().replace(",","."));
      $(this).find('td.mcost_el').html(count*price);
});
```

Which will -

- Loop through each table row
- For the current table row, find the count and price variables by
  extracting them from the `<td>` relevant to the current row using `$(this).find('td.<classname>')` syntax
- Multiply the two variables and and add the result to the total `<td>`

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/AVGgU/1

Comment: No need to `parseFloat` twice.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something along the line of

```
elements = $("body").children().length
```

have a look, [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: you can also add a filter inside the children function for more specific children as well.

Comment: yes, I just didn't understand what exactly he wanted to count

Comment: `mcount_el` contains the count of the elements. `mprice_el` contains the price. `mcost_el` contains the computed cost.

Comment: yea, now I read it again, the title didn't match the question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#table_id tr").each(function() {
  var count = parseInt($(this).find(".mcount_el").text());
  var price = parseFloat($(this).find(".mprice_el").text());
  var cost = count * price;
  $(this).find(".mcost_el").text(cost.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: count is not an integer (3,9) in the second row. `parseFloat` wont treat `,` as decimal separator. See: http://jsfiddle.net/78UDy/

Comment: I presumed this would be handled automatically as a localization issue, as long as the local user's country treated , as a decimal separator. I've never had to deal with such matters myself, so if I'm wrong, do what Jamiec does and add a `.replace(",",".")`